# Downloaded XNA 4.0 Beta, now when I run my emulator does not appear

Tags: c#, xna

It was working before update, now when I run debug, my phone emulator does not run with the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any errors? I'd say to completely 100% uninstall all xna/phone bits and reinstall ... things can get funky if there are any leftovers from a previous install

Comment: That did the trick,  didn't want to restore to that(as its a longish process) but it worked